# Remove action on specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have function to filter post in Ajax:

```
function load_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . 'scripts.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

    wp_localize_script('ajax' , 'wp_ajax',
        array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
        );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax' );

function filter_ajax($taxonomy) {


$category = $_POST['category'];


$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 50,
  'category__in' => 6
);


if(isset($category)) {
  
    $args['category__in'] = array($category);
}


        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if($query->have_posts()) :
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
                the_content('<p>', '</p>');
            endwhile;
        endif;
            wp_reset_postdata(); 


    die();
}
```

I want to `remove_action` in specific page (faq). I trying with this:

```
  function faq_disable() {
      if( is_page('faq')) {
        remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax' );
        remove_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax' );
      } else {
          echo "Not working";
      }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'faq_disable' );
```

but that is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Edited//

**FAQ.php**

```
<div class="js-filter">
    <?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'child_of' => 10,
    'exclude' => array(1),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query('cat=10');

    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
            the_content('<p>', '</p>');
        endwhile;
        endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<div class="categories">

<ul>
    <?php 
        $cat_args = array(
            'exclude' => array(1),
            'child_of' => 10
        );
        ?>

<?php 
global $post;
$category = reset(get_the_category($post->ID));
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>

        <li class="js-filter-item"><a href="#">All</a></li>

        <?php $categories = get_categories($cat_args); foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
        <li class="js-filter-item"><a data-category="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>" href="<?= get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?= $cat->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**products.php**

```
<div class="js-filter">
    <?php
    
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'child_of' => 6,
    'exclude' => array(1,10),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query('cat=6');

    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
            the_content('<p>', '</p>');
        endwhile;
        endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<div class="categories">

<ul>
    <?php 
        $cat_args = array(
            'exclude' => array(1,10),
            'child_of' => 6
        );
        ?>

<?php 
global $post;
$category = reset(get_the_category($post->ID));
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>

        <li class="js-filter-item"><a href="#">All</a></li>

        <?php $categories = get_categories($cat_args); foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
        <li class="js-filter-item"><a data-category="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>" href="<?= get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?= $cat->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
  (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var category = $(this).data('category');

            $.ajax({
                url:wp_ajax.ajax_url,
                data: { action: 'filter', category: category },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('.js-filter').html(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    console.warn(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you please, explain your problem a little more?

Comment: @NowshadRuhaniChowdhury the problem is with ARGS. For the "FAQ" page they must be different and for the "PRODUCCTS" page they must be different. I figured that on one of the pages I would turn off the action ... I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. As you could apply the same logic to the ajax filter.

```
function load_scripts() {
    if( is_page('faq')) return; // Check for page prior to even enqueuing
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . 'scripts.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

    wp_localize_script('ajax' , 'wp_ajax',
        array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
        );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax' );

function filter_ajax($taxonomy) {


$category = $_POST['category'];
    
    if (is_page('faq') ) {
        $cat__in = 10;
    } else {
        $cat__in = 6;
    }

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 50,
  'category__in' => $cat__in,
);

if(isset($category)) {
  
    $args['category__in'] = array($category);
}


        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if($query->have_posts()) :
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
                the_content('<p>', '</p>');
            endwhile;
        endif;
            wp_reset_postdata(); 


    die();
}
```

Comment: works great. What do I have to do if I want to change "category__in" in the "FAQ" page?

Comment: Assuming you mean the $args['category__in']? and what do you want to change it to?

Comment: the "PRODUCTS" page uses "category__in" => 6. I need the "FAQ" page to use "category__in" => 10

Comment: Updated the answer. Basically, you can use is_page to check that as well and set it.

Comment: thanks for trying but it doesn't work. Now it doesn't show any posts.

Comment: haha Sorry, I actually removed the $args section when I copy/pasted

Comment: still not working :( I edited my post to show you my faq.php and products.php

Comment: Actually, you reset it after the $args = and setting $cat__in you say if is set then overwrite it. Is $category getting set by the $_POST? if so it wouldn't matter what we set it as.

Comment: yes, but it still doesn't work and it shows posts from category ID = 6 regardless of the page

Comment: So at a glance it looks like the query is also wrong. $query = new WP_Query('cat=10'); should be $query = new WP_Query(array( 'cat' => 10 ));

Comment: If this is executed within an ajax request, is_page() won't be set. the page you're making the request from was a previous request. you need to set something on the originating page to pass with your ajax request to let it know it's for your special case page. do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: you could pass it via the JS but would need to see how you are using it.

Comment: Sure. I edited post. Please take a look.

Comment: So for the filter you are already getting it as $category = $_POST['category']; is the category passed via your ajax - var category = $(this).data('category'); Easy way to check that is to console.log it. Also are you able to share the URL for this? May make it easier.

Comment: here is products: https://klienci.scepter.agency/piekarnia/category/produkty/

Comment: here is FAQ: https://klienci.scepter.agency/piekarnia/faq/

Comment: At a glance you actually have a 404 on the scripts.js

Comment: a fact I have already corrected

Comment: You need to flag this as the correct answer for your original question if you are going to continue to open new posts for basically a continuation of what this turned into.